# Pact in Jenkinsfile: can-i-deploy check

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pact

We are using PACT (https://pact.io/) in our project. The can-i-deploy check, whether the deployment can be executed is done like this:

Jenkins Environment Variables (see <JENKINS_URL>/configure)

```
PACT_BROKER_URL
PACT_RUBY_STANDALONE_VERSION
```

(PACT_RUBY_STANDALONE_VERSION from https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-ruby-standalone/releases)

Jenkinsfile:

```
environment {
    SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME = sourceBranchName(env.BRANCH_NAME, env.CHANGE_BRANCH)
}
```

...

```
def sourceBranchName(String branchName, String changeBranchName) {
   return changeBranchName == null ? branchName : changeBranchName
}
```

...

```
   stage('can-i-deploy') {
        steps {
            withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'XXX', passwordVariable: 'PACT_BROKER_PASSWORD', usernameVariable: 'PACT_BROKER_USERNAME')]) {
                sh "curl -LO https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-ruby-standalone/releases/download/v${PACT_RUBY_STANDALONE_VERSION}/pact-${PACT_RUBY_STANDALONE_VERSION}-linux-x86_64.tar.gz"
                sh "tar xzf pact-${PACT_RUBY_STANDALONE_VERSION}-linux-x86_64.tar.gz"
                echo "Performing can-i-deploy check"
                sh "pact/bin/./pact-broker can-i-deploy --broker-base-url=${PACT_BROKER_URL} --broker-username=${PACT_BROKER_USERNAME}  --broker-password=${PACT_BROKER_PASSWORD} --pacticipant=project-frontend --latest=${env.SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME} --pacticipant=project-backend --latest=${env.SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME} --pacticipant=other-project-backend --latest=${env.SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME}"
            }
        }
    }
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak for Jenkins, but there are two things worth changing in the arguments sent to `can-i-deploy`:

1. It's no recommended to use the `latest` flag. You should use the `--version` to indicate the version of the application you are deploying and the `--to` flag to denote the target environment (`latest` runs the risk of race conditions with builds giving you false positives/negatives)
2. You don't need to specify compatible other projects, can-i-deploy will automatically detect all dependent components.

So it would look more like this

```
can-i-deploy --broker-base-url=${PACT_BROKER_URL} --broker-username=${PACT_BROKER_USERNAME}  --broker-password=${PACT_BROKER_PASSWORD} --pacticipant=project-frontend --version some-sha-1234 --to prod
```

If you have access to docker, you might prefer to use our [container](https://docs.pact.io/implementation_guides/cli/#pact-cli).

P.S. if you simply export the following environment variables you can drop them off the argument list also:

- `PACT_BROKER_BASE_URL` (please note the minor difference from what you're using)
- `PACT_BROKER_USERNAME`
- `PACT_BROKER_PASSWORD`